# Xgboost objective rank is position sensitive

Tags: machine-learning, ranking, xgboost

I'm running xgboost with objective `rank:NDGC` and the input format of the dataset needed to be in libsvm fomart
and I'm wondering if the libsvm is position sensitive for this objective as we know that the position is important for search (higher position higher probability to click)

libsvm example of 1 query group:

```
0 qid:6 1:1 3:5 4:65 5:281 6:2 7:15 
0 qid:6 1:2 3:15 4:68 5:13 6:2 7:14
1 qid:6 1:3 3:75 4:65 5:11 6:2 7:9 
0 qid:6 1:4 3:20 4:65 5:113 6:2 7:10 
2 qid:6 1:5 3:5 4:68 5:83 6:2 7:51 
0 qid:6 1:6 3:20 4:65 5:116 6:2 7:3 
1 qid:6 1:7 3:25 4:65
```

Is the ordering of the position relevance?

I know that for NDCG the position is important, how the position is taking into account in Xgboost implementation